# Display plain PHP code

Tags: centos, php, amazon-ec2, centos7, apache2

I am using Amazon EC2, CentOS 7 x64_86, 1GB RAM.

(1) Run command

```
php -v
```

result

```
PHP 7.0.24 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2017 10:10:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

(2) Run command

```
httpd -v
```

result

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Oct 19 2017 20:39:16
```

(3) Run command

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
```

Result

```
#
# This configuration file enables the default "Welcome" page if there
# is no default index page present for the root URL.  To disable the
# Welcome page, comment out all the lines below.
#
# NOTE: if this file is removed, it will be restored on upgrades.
#
#<LocationMatch "^/+$">
#    Options -Indexes
#    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
#</LocationMatch>

<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
Alias /noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
Alias /noindex/css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
```

Error

[image]

and

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: And what makes you think the `welcome.conf` has something to do with this?

Comment: you need to load mod_php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you've got PHP from, as the version shipped in CentOS 7 is 5.4.16. Anyway, the stock `php` package installs configuration for Apache so that `*.php` files get fed through the PHP interpreter, (so they don't just return the source code). You need something like this added to your Apache configuration:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

This is based on the standard `php` package configuration. If you've compiled PHP yourself you will need to adapt it to fit.